# Fixed vertical sidebar with full width image background

Tags: css, background-image, css-position

I have two divs - one is fixed on the left side of the page as a side nav, and the other I have a background image that I would like to be fluid, and cover the width of the div. I looked and couldn't find anything as specific as what I am looking for. Below is my code.

```css
.geodeticContainer {
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 800px;
}
.content {
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin-left: 300px;
}
 .image {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("images/geodetics.jpg") norepeat center center fixed;
  z-index:999;
 }
.description {
 position: fixed;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #eaeaed;
 padding: 20px;
 color: #0072bc;
}
```

```html
<div class="geodeticContainer">

 <div class="description">
    This is the content of the side bar. There will be a descriptive paragraph about the image on the right hand side.
    </div>
 <div class="content">
    <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

I apologize if that has been done and I just couldn't find it because I don't know how to describe what I am looking for. Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What is your issue? What is your expected output.

Comment: Is this the rule you are looking for? `.content { background-size: cover; }`

Comment: I would like for the background image to be 100% of the width of the right div but I can't seem to get it show up using the css rule 'background-image'. .content { background-size: cover;} doesn't work for me, i'm using chrome?

I can make the image show up in the HTML but cannot control it being responsive with the site. To give you an idea, the img im using is 1024 x 2452

Comment: Do you want the background image to just be on the content area (non-sidebar) or the whole page?

Comment: Just the content area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the image responsive within it's `div` using **flexbox**.

I had to adjust the `margin-left` property a little and I replaced your `image` class with an `<img>` tag to simplify.

```css
.geodeticContainer {
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 800px;
}
.content {
 display: flex;
 margin-left: 340px;
}
.content div img {
  width: 100%;
}
.description {
 position: fixed;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #eaeaed;
 padding: 20px;
 color: #0072bc;
}
```

```html
<div class="geodeticContainer">

 <div class="description">
    This is the content of the side bar. There will be a descriptive paragraph about the image on the right hand side.
    </div>
 <div class="content">
    <div><img src="images/geodetics.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want to achieve but hopefully this will help

**UPDATE:**
I updated the code, please check snippet below or go to [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/jx4s4cbk/) - ps: re-size the screen to see responsiveness. Hope this help

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
#img {
  background: url("http://s10.postimg.org/3nmoewzq1/dramatic_landscape_191458.jpg") top left no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <p>
          This is the content of the side bar. There will be a descriptive paragraph about the image on the right hand side. This is the content of the side bar. There will be a descriptive paragraph about the image on the right hand side.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-10" id="img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Although a cool effect, no quite what I was looking for. I would like only the content area on the right to have the background image if at all possible have it be responsive. Sorry, i'm a designer learning how to code and not that great :/ I do appreciate your feed though!